# Formally proving that a function is $O(x^n)$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Say I have a function

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d,\text{ where }a > 0.
\end{equation*}

It's clear that for a high enough value of $x$, the $x^3$ term will dominate and I can say $f(x) \in O(x^3)$, but this doesn't seem very formal.

The formal definition is $f(x) \in O(g(x))$ if constants $k, x_0 > 0$ exist, such that $0 \le f(x) \le kg(x)$ for all $x > x_0$.

My question is, what are appropriate values for $k$ and $x_0$? It's easy enough to find ones that apply (say $k = a + b + c + d$). By the formal definition, all I have to do is show that these numbers exist, so does it actually matter which numbers I use? For some value of $x$, $k$ could be anywhere from $1$ to $a + b + c + d + ... $. From my understanding, it doesn't matter what numbers I pick as long as they 'work', but is this right? It seems too easy.

Thanks

Comment: I changed some of the c's to k's because I think there was a clash there - hope that it was correct to do so.

Comment: Looks fine to me. You missed one though -- I fixed it :-P

Comment: If $a < 0$, then the $0 \le kg(x)$ is violated... Perhaps a different definition? Or can $k < 0$?

Comment: @Moron: Yeah, I think we should have $|f(x)|<k|g(x)|$ for $x>x_0$. For instance, $sin(x)=O(1)$ and the defintion by Joel doesn't give this.

Comment: @alex: Yeah, since this seems like homework, just trying to make sure Joel knows the right definition taught in their class :-)

Comment: @Moron: Seems a confusing homework problem where they use the same notation for a non-standard defintion. I agree probably homework.

Comment: @Moron: It's an algorithms class, so I'm used to assuming that $a > 0$, although now I realize that it's not appropriate for a question on a math site to exclude them. For the record, this isn't a specific homework question - I don't think anything given in my course will ever be this general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument you are getting at as I understand is is, roughly: $x^n \in O(x^n)$ and thus $kx^n \in O(x^n)$, so $f(x)$ acts like $O(x^3) + O(x^2) + O(x) + O(1)$ which can be reduced to $O(x^3)$.

So the theorem we would like to prove now is that for $n\geq m$: $f \in O(x^n)$ and $g \in O(x^m)$ implies $f + g \in O(x^n)$. Once we have this you just add up the monomials of the polynomial and that proves the result.

Look at what we have, from the definitions:

$$f \in O(x^n) \Rightarrow \exists x_0, k,\;\; \forall x>x_0,\;\; f(x) \leq kx^n$$

$$g \in O(x^m) \Rightarrow \exists x_1, k',\;\; \forall x>x_1,\;\; g(x) \leq kx^m$$

Let $x_2$ be the maximum of $x_0$ and $x_1$, $k''$ be the maximum of $k$ and $k'$ and add these inequalities:

$$\forall x>x_2,\;\; (f+g)(x) \leq kx^n + k'x^m \leq k''(x^n + x^m) \leq 2 k'' x^n $$

Now the pair of values $(x_2,2k'')$ prove that $f+g \in O(x^n)$.

---

To consider abstract functions like this makes the proof very easy, but it is clear that the values we exhibit to prove the existential may not be the *best*, although we still prove the theorem in an effective way. In particular, you could do a very detailed analysis of the functions in specific cases to get very tight bounds - in this lucky case it's not needed which is why the theorem is easier to prove in the abstract case.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT** $\quad\rm  ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d\  \le \ (|a|+|b|+|c|+|d|)\ x^3 \ $  for $\rm\ x > 1$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a function $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

A really simple method (that works when $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials) of determining a constant that works is the following. Consider

$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

If the limit exists and if a constant $0\leq C< \infty$. Then $C+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$ is a constant that works. To see this just apply the definition of the limit. $\forall \epsilon>0$ there exists a $x_0(\epsilon)$ such that $\forall x>x_0(\epsilon)$ we have

$\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-C\right|<\epsilon$

That is

$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} < C+\epsilon$

Now you know the constant from calculating the limit and know the existence of $x_0$. Since you are always considering asymptotics when using this definition you are never concerned with the value of $x_0$ (only that it exists)

It does not matter what constants you use and someone could easily use different constants to get $f(x)=O(g(x))$. This notation is to compare the growth rate of two functions.

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ does not exist or is hard to calculate then as long as you can bound it above you still have $f(x)=O(g(x))$